# Pandas: How to get the location of value without column name and index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

There is a dataframe below:

```
Unnamed:0|Unnamed:1|Unnamed:2
Apple    |         |50
Orange   |         |60
Banana   |         |70
```

How can I get the location of value '60' by method **df[index, index]** without column name?
And the value of '60' is a dynamic result, I only can make sure its location is fixed( at the same row of 'Orange', and next to it with two columns)

Comment: What if all the table is dynamic expect the column of 'Orange', so I only can locate value '60' by using this(at the same row of 'Orange', and next to it with two columns)

Answer (score 2):

I think you need for selecting second row and third column methods [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html)
[`DataFrame.insert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html) or [`DataFrame.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iat.html), there is used `[1,2]` because pandas count from `0` - so first `Apple` should be selected by `[0,0]`:

```
df.iloc[1,2]
```

Or:

```
df.iat[1,2]
```

For `Orange` use second row, first column:

```
df.iloc[1,0]
df.iat[1,0]
```

EDIT:

If need third column same like `Orange` position:

```
df.iloc[(df['fruit'] == 'Orange').to_numpy(), 2]
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answer. What if locating it only by value 'Orange'?

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'fruit': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Banana'], 
        'price': ['50', '60', '70']}  
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data) 
df.loc[df['fruit'] == 'Orange']
```

Comment: df.loc[df['fruit'] == 'Orange'].index to get index and df.loc[df['fruit'] == 'Orange'].price to get price.... return array if found multiple values